# Ionic framework,Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

The problem which i have been facing now is that after `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user_info')));`
how can i put this string in `$scope` object ?

please suggest something for my problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419566/updating-a-single-item-in-angular-scope-object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to define an AngularJS [controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) and then bind it to your Ionic view with the [ng-controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) directive. Below is an example — I recommend playing around with it on [play.ionic.io](http://play.ionic.io).

**js**

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic']).controller('MyController', function($scope) {

  // localStorage.setItem('user_info', JSON.stringify('Hello World'));
  $scope.userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user_info'));

});
```

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">LocalStorage Example</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="MyController">
        <h1>{{userInfo}}</h1>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

angular.module('app', ['ionic']).controller('MyController', function($scope) {

// localStorage.setItem('user_info', JSON.stringify('Hello World'));
  $scope.userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user_info'));

});

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)